# Github stopped working recently, 07/26/2014?

Tags: github, ssl

I'm a pro user of github until it stopped working on the last saturday, the 26. of July, 2014. Since then, i'm becoming in my browser following SSL error:

[image: github in my chrome]

My IDE (IntelliJ) is becoming the same error, so it is not only tied together with the browser:

[image: IDE Error]

When i open github.com in my freshly resetted Safari (so i can see the certificate again), i look into the certificate details and as it seems to me, the cert is clearly expired:

[image: expired certificate?]

Though, i can open the page in safari but i never have seen it so broken like this:

[image: take your shit together, tyr.. i mean github]

I can't find anything in the interwebs about such problems on github.com but as it seems to me - this is completely not client-relate.. i really start to believe that this is just a problem of github itself.

So, does anybody know something about? Are they going to fix that? How big is the chance that such things are happening again? I mean, an SSL cert normaly expires once a year, if you're not ready for that case... then i really tend to move on to some other service because with every further day i can't push my commits to my rep, it feels more bad :-(

Thanks for any advice!

PS: It seems funny but on the same day, odesk.com stopped working too! With the exact same behavior and it seems, also they have an expired certificate in their intermediate-chain!

Comment: ok i just realize here on work that even our own company certs seem to be expired in my computer which are clearly not expired at all - my collegue's computer shows the same "DigiCert HighAssurance EV Root CA" as valid until 2017.. :(

Comment: Update your ssl CA certs and this should go away. The issue you are seeing is ssl cert marked as expired.

Comment: Sorry about the issues. I am on Debian ... so apt-get update ca-certificates does the trick. Maybe some missed OS X update? or probably a recipe in the Brew system could do the trick more easier.