# GitHub for Windows not working after install

Tags: windows-7, windows, git, github-desktop

Today I have installed GitHub For Windows. I had installed GitHub for Windows earlier and at that time it worked fine, but due to some reason I had to uninstall it.

Today when I installed GitHub again it installed perfectly. But after installation when I click on the icon, GitHub does not open. I checked Task Manager for processes and for some time I can see Github.exe, but after some time it disappears.

When it did'nt work I uninstalled and installed again, but the results are the same.

When I try to open it, only the loading symbols comes up.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is completely on topic.

Comment: Related to this: http://superuser.com/questions/789029/github-stopped-working-recently-07-26-2014 ?

Comment: @Hannu No it's not related

Comment: @Hannu One of my friends was able to do it perfectly on his own computer.

Comment: firewall too strict?

Comment: @Hannu I can access github ... There is no network problem. Only problem is that the app does not even Open after installation.

Comment: Can you access the system logs _right-click My Computer, select Manage..._, might there be something related to this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16006/discussion-between-kartik-and-hannu).

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea how to get you further than this - and have no Windows install to 'aid' me. ^ I had just seen the other posting though.

Comment: Is your msysgit install trashed? Windows requires a separate version of git than other OSes, msysgit, and github *probably* comes packaged with that. I would try to run git from the command line and see if you get any errors.. Also try completely uninstalling msysgit, github, restarting, and then reinstalling github for windows.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem as you had. I installed GitHub before, and it worked fine. I uninstalled it then trying to reinstall it, but nothing happens whenever I click the GitHub icon.

Deleting the GitHub folders left behind from `AppData\Local` and `Roaming` folders helped me solve my problem. Then I reinstalled GitHub and now it works.

- From the Windows Start menu, choose Run (or <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
- Enter the following, depending on your version of Windows, and then click the OK button:

On Windows Vista or higher, delete the `%LocalAppData%\GitHub` and the `%AppData%\GitHub` directories.

On Windows XP, delete the `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\GitHub` directory.

Source: [Uninstalling GitHub for Windows](https://help.github.com/articles/uninstalling-github-for-windows/)

Comment: I have GitHub Desktop and it wasn't opening after I updated it. I opened `%LocalAppData%\GitHubDesktop` and I saw 2 applications. `GitHubDesktop.exe` and `GitHub Desktop.exe` (space). I opened the one with the newer modified date and it opened.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to delete the GitHub folder as described above, end the ssh-agent.exe process from Task Manager in Windows.  Then, immediately delete the folder.

`Task Manager` >> `Processes` >> `ssh-agent.exe`>> `End Process`