# Github Won't Open

Tags: windows-7, git, github, github-desktop

Similar to this issue:

[GitHub for Windows not working after install](https://superuser.com/questions/789120/github-for-windows-not-working-after-install)

When I install the Github desktop on Windows 7, it opens briefly in the task manager and shuts down.  I have re-installed numerous times to no avail.  There is no error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked in the Task Manager to see if the executable is already running?  That was a known issue for a while.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate, as you have not expressed that you tried anything other than reinstalling it.  The answers on the dupe suggest doing more than just reinstalling.  If you feel your question is different, please edit it and add information that makes it appear as such. Include ALL things you've tried already, and what the results were.  Also, check the Event Log for errors that may be related.

Comment: I uninstalled the same way it was done in the duplicate, nothing.  I did everything suggested there, nothing.  Still sitting here with a broken application.

Comment: And as I said in the original post, no, it isn't already running.  I fail to see how this is a duplicate, but whatever.

Comment: Have you disabled any anti-virus?