# Why is GitHub Desktop not letting me interact with it?

Tags: windows-10, github-desktop

It's been a while since I've used my GitHub Desktop, on Windows 10, but when I decided to try and open it again I ran into a weird issue: GitHub Desktop wouldn't let me click on anything except the minimize, maximize, and close.

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall it, but that did not work.

Before the Login screen comes up on the client, there is a screen that flashes before it that has the text:

> Drop to clone long-repository-name

With some other words that are all on the same line overlapping each other.

Not too sure of the version I'm using, but it is the most recent download off the GitHub Desktop site.

I have tried looking online for anyone with a similar issue, but all I could find were authentication issues. I did try asking this on StackOverflow where it was speculated that it might be an input issue because of the screen that flashes before the login. It was also suggested that SuperUser may be a better place to ask this question.

If anyone knows of a fix, or if I have clearly done something wrong please let me know.

[image: Here is what it looks like.]

Comment: Relate https://superuser.com/questions/789120 not sure if it is a dupe.

Comment: @James No, it is a slightly different issue, but I did try the suggestion to delete the GitHub folders in the LocalAppData and AppData folders and reinstall GitHub. However, that did not work. I did try the Beta they have up and that is working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a solution to the exact problem as it is a work around.
After trying to delete everything GitHub related from my machine and reinstalling GitHub Desktop with no success, I did see that GitHub has a Beta out for their new [desktop version](https://desktop.github.com/).

Upon installing the Beta, I find I am able to actually use it like I could previously with the official GitHub Desktop.

That is why I am listing this as answered.